# Open specific tab of the control panel programmatically

Tags: c++, winapi, control-panel

The Windows API has an interface [IOpenControlPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775392%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which allows you to open any part of the control panel you wish from C++.  However, beyond opening a specific page, there doesn't seem to be a way to open to a tab on that page directly.

I'm looking to jump to the "Recording" section of the Sound control panel item, for example.  How might I achieve that?